# React component state changes after following function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to show some info based on what item was pressed.
To do so I am modifying the state's selectedSchedule value to different values according to which button was pressed.

The info(for now, the selectedSchedule value itself) displayed is always the one that should've been before. When you press 'Segmented' the displayed text is '', the value selectedSchedule was initialized with. Then, when you go back, and press, 'Uberman' 'Segmented appears'.

I don't know if this is an issue with the component lifecycle or if javascript/React handle functions asynchronously; the function written after setState() seems to get called first.

```
//SleepSchedules.js 
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Text, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';
import ScheduleItem from './ScheduleItem';

export default class SleepSchedules extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedSchedule: ''};
  }

   _handlePress(schedule){
    this.setState({
      selectedSchedule: schedule
    });

    this._navScheduleItem()
  }

   _navScheduleItem(){

     this.props.navigator.push({
         title: 'ScheduleItem',
         component: ScheduleItem,
         passProps: {scheduleName: this.state.selectedSchedule}
     })
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={{paddingTop:64}}>
                <Content>
                    <Card>
                        <CardItem button
                          onPress={()=> this._handlePress('Segmented')} >
                            <Text>Segmented</Text>
                        </CardItem>

                        <CardItem button
                          onPress={()=> this._handlePress('Everyman')}>
                          <Text>Everyman</Text>
                        </CardItem>

                        <CardItem button
                          onPress={()=> this._handlePress('Uberman')}>
                          <Text>Uberman</Text>
                        </CardItem>
                   </Card>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the component it's passing it's props to:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Text, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';
import ComingSoon from './ComingSoon';

export default class ScheduleItem extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
     {this.props.scheduleName}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Never mutate props. Consider it immutable. this.props.navigator is mutating.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson nope. In this case, it's not object mutation (not pushing into array, as it might look like). It pushing screen using navigation lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, `setState` is async in this case (it is sync, in some special cases, lol, right?). That means, never rely on setState being sync...

There are 2 possible solutions.

First: Don't wait until state is changed. Pass received value manually, immediately.

```
_handlePress(selectedSchedule) {
    this.setState({ selectedSchedule });
    this._navScheduleItem(selectedSchedule)
}

_navScheduleItem(scheduleName) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'ScheduleItem',
        component: ScheduleItem,
        passProps: { scheduleName },
    })
}
```

Second: Wait until state change propagate. Read updated state value.

```
_handlePress(selectedSchedule){
    this.setState({ selectedSchedule }, () => {
        this._navScheduleItem()
    });
}

_navScheduleItem(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'ScheduleItem',
        component: ScheduleItem,
        passProps: { scheduleName: this.state.selectedSchedule }
    })
}
```